# Всплывающее меню поверх Acticity

Tags: java, android

Я хочу сделать всплывающее меню/окно, которое не закрывает полностью активити(есть отступы) + при нажатии кнопки в этом самом меню оно закрывалось бы

Comment: и в чем вопрос, вам нужно разрешение, чтобы это сделать или что? Как здесь [задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы получить полезный ответ

Comment: @pavlofff я хочу его вообще сделать

Comment: ну делайте, что уж ... вопрос то в чем? прочитайте по ссылке выше, как задавать здесь вопросы, чтобы получать на них ответы и оформите свой вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать ответ.

Comment: alertDialog сделай

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)

Ну и упрощенный пример.

Создаем подкласс *DialogFragment*, в рамках вопроса важными являются методы *onStart()* и *onCreateDialog()*, ими определяются размеры, вид, поведение диалога. Передачу данных в диалог, осуществляем аналогично обычным фрагментам, опять же по простому, в демонстрационных целях, *newInstance(...)*, *onCreateDialog(...)*

```
public class SomeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private static final int MARGIN_H = 100;
    private static final int MARGIN_V = 200;

    private String name;

    static SomeDialogFragment newInstance(String text) {
        SomeDialogFragment fragment = new SomeDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        args.putString("name", text);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        //dialog.setCancelable(true);
        //dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(?);

        name = getArguments().getString("name");

        return dialog;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_something, container, false);

        setupUI(name);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (getDialog() != null) {
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
            int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
            lp.copyFrom(getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes());
            lp.height = height - MARGIN_V;
            lp.width = width - MARGIN_H;
            // На "весь" экран, поверх Activity, с отступами от края экрана    
            getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
        }
    }

    private void setupUI(String name){
        //UI

    }

}
```

Когда надо вызываем:

```
void showSomeDialog() {
    DialogFragment someDialog = SomeDialogFragment.newInstance("Привет, я dialog fragment, как ты хотел");
    someDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "somedialog");
}
```

А "кнопку" добавить, думаю не проблема.